# CSS for email sent to developer after applying for a job looks to need some tidying up?

Tags: discussion, status-planned, design, stack-overflow-jobs

After applying for a job you are sent an auto email.
Here's what it looks like:

[image]

There seems to be some weird indents.  Also some things to consider:

- Consider the font style
- Consider changing the tags to look like tags and add more spacing
- Left align these

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately these emails do look terrible in a few versions of Outlook. Email styling is an utter mess in general, but we're running most of the emails through Litmus in the coming weeks so these kinds of bugs will be fixed in the near future.